# I do not understand substitution

Tags: substitution

[Question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyyeH.png)

Like described in image, I do not know how P1 become like that. Especially about why p1 is removed.
Is there any formula used for this question?

Comment: $x=A+Bx\implies x=\frac A{1-B}$

Comment: Not really substitution. More like algebra solving $P_1$

Comment: Include the question as text, not as an image, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is of the form

$$P_1=a+bP_1$$ which you rewrite

$$(1-b)P_1=a,$$
$$P_1=\frac a{1-b}.$$